# error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String - Java

Tags: java

This is just a part of my code that I have problem troubleshooting.

```
static int checkConcat(String number) {
        TreeSet<Integer> a = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<number.length(); i++) {
            a.add(Integer.parseInt(number.charAt(i)));
        }
}
```

The error that I'm getting is :

> error: incompatible types: char cannot be converted to String

What's wrong with the code, and how can I solve it in this context?

Comment: `Integer.parseInt` expects a `String`, not a `char`.

Comment: Use `Character.digit`.

Comment: You asked a (simple) question, and you've got several answers. So, why didn't you accepted one of them? It seems to me that in these answers is a at least one solution for you.

Comment: @Dukeling, I didn't mean to be rude, but for **this** kind of question and these answers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily convert the char to String.

```
char aCharacter = 'c';
String aCharacterAsString = String.valueOf(aCharacter);
```

So in your case:

```
a.add(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(number.charAt(i))));
```

Answer (score 3):

[`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) has the argument type `String`, not `char` as returned by `number.charAt(i)`.

Convert to a `String`:

```
a.add(Integer.parseInt("" + number.charAt(i)));
```

Comment: Can you rewrite the solution to solve the above problem using my code?

Comment: Of course I can, but why don't you try it yourself?

Answer (score 0):

A single character is `char`, not `String`. Although you could construct a single-character string from `char` using a method described below, parsing a number digit-by-digit should be done with a different API:

```
for(int i=0; i<number.length(); i++) {
    a.add(Character.digit(number.charAt(i), 10));
}
```

To construct a single-character string from `char` in Java, use `String.valueOf` method:

```
String singleDigit = String.valueOf(number.charAt(i));
```

Answer (score 0):

`charAt` returns one character of the string, therefore the return type is `char` not `string` to convert to string use the `String.valueOf` method:

```
String.valueOf(number.charAt(i))
```

Or don't use `Integer.parse` just subtract `'0'` from the character to convert it to the digit value. This would be a simpler more efficient way to convert a single digit value.

```
number.charAt(i) -'0'
```

Comment: The trick of subtracting zero character, borrowed from C, was foreign to Java since day one, because Java standard library has `Character.digit` method. To be honest, I was unaware of its existence for many years, diligently writing `ch-'0'` in my Java code.